# Bootstrap dropdown menu shifting to top left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am creating a `navbar` with three `nav-items` each having a `dropdown-menu` class added. The first `nav-item`'s `dropdown-menu` is being displayed fine but for remaining two the `dropdown-menu` seems to move to top left.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pkg9uLzf/). I did added `dropdown-menu-right` but then it still isn't aligned perfectly below `nav-item`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class name `dropdown` to each of the `li` items that are drop-downs (it is missing in the second and third dropdown). It should look like this: `<li class="nav-item dropdown">`

Here you can find some more info regarding how Bootstrap's dropdown work: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/